# regular expression to find value in csv string

Tags: java, regex, csv

Source String:

```
1,4,test,v,4t,10,20,more
```

Need to use a regular expression to see if this string contains any one of those values.  So the question is:

```
Does the source string have 1 in it?  Yes
Does the source string have 10 in it? Yes
Does the source string have v in it? Yes

Does the source string have 01 in it? No
Does the source string have va in it? No
Does the source string have test,v in it?  (invalid input, so don't have to worry about it)
```

P.S.  The core language is Java.

---

Response to: "Any reason why you aren't using a dedicated regex parser?"
Answer:  Well, I am working in Java, so will be using the java.util.regex class.  From what I know of regular expression, for the most part they are language neutral, so I don't fully understand what you are driving at, can you expound on it a bit?

---

Response to: "Why do you need regex? You could use separate contains() calls in a loop, which would be easier to maintain and understand."
Answer: It is my impression that a well written regular expression will execute faster and be easier to read, assuming it is commented correctly.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a dedicated regex parser?

Comment: Why do you need regex? You could use separate `contains()` calls in a loop, which would be easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: Consider using [this CSV Parser](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: If you think a regular expression will *faster and easier to read* than regular idiomatic procedural code, you haven't tried to read very many regular expressions or profiled them. There is no such thing as a *well written regular expression* anymore than there is a such a thing as *well written php* ( or perl )!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and efficient :)

```
public class App {

    static String answer(int index) {
        return index < 0 ? "No" : "Yes";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "1,4,test,v,4t,10,20,more";

        String[] arr = line.split(",");

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have 1 in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "1"))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have 10 in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "10"))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have v in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "v"))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have 01 in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "01"))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have va in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "va"))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Does the source string have test,v in it? %s", answer(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "test,v"))));

    }
}
```

Out:

```
Does the source string have 1 in it? Yes
Does the source string have 10 in it? Yes
Does the source string have v in it? Yes
Does the source string have 01 in it? No
Does the source string have va in it? No
Does the source string have test,v in it? No
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like contains() would do fine for this. You could also use a StringTokenizer and run through each token and see if it is equal to another string.

If you MUST use regex then this would work `\,?([^,]+),?\g` to find every element in the CSV. Specifically to check if a particular element was in the string:

`String csv = "1,4,test,v,4t,10,20,more";
System.out.println(csv.matches(",?(" + test + "),?"));`

EDIT: a regex is not necessarily faster or cleaner, depends on implementation. I'll put up an example if you like.